# How to get the checked radiobutton from a groupbox in pyqt

Tags: pyqt4

I have a groupbox with some radiobuttons. How do I get to know which one which is checked.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use button groups. For example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MoodExample(QGroupBox):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MoodExample, self).__init__()

        # Create an array of radio buttons
        moods = [QRadioButton("Happy"), QRadioButton("Sad"), QRadioButton("Angry")]

        # Set a radio button to be checked by default
        moods[0].setChecked(True)

        # Radio buttons usually are in a vertical layout
        button_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create a button group for radio buttons
        self.mood_button_group = QButtonGroup()

        for i in xrange(len(moods)):
            # Add each radio button to the button layout
            button_layout.addWidget(moods[i])
            # Add each radio button to the button group & give it an ID of i
            self.mood_button_group.addButton(moods[i], i)
            # Connect each radio button to a method to run when it's clicked
            self.connect(moods[i], SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.radio_button_clicked)

        # Set the layout of the group box to the button layout
        self.setLayout(button_layout)

    #Print out the ID & text of the checked radio button
    def radio_button_clicked(self):
        print(self.mood_button_group.checkedId())
        print(self.mood_button_group.checkedButton().text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mood_example = MoodExample()
mood_example.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I found more information at:

http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=387&key=QButtonGroupClick

http://www.pythonschool.net/pyqt/radio-button-widget/

Comment: `button_group.checkedButton()` is the important part here, in case somebody doesn't want to skim through all the code.

Answer (score 4):

you will need to iterate through all the radio buttons in the groupbox and check for the property `isChecked()` of each radiobox.

eg:

```
radio1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button 1")
radio2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button 2")
radio3 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button 3")

for i in range(1,4):
    buttonname = "radio" + str(i)
    if buttonname.isChecked():
        print buttonname + "is Checked"
```

for reference, check http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qradiobutton.html

Comment: Great solution. but How can I change if I don't know how many radiobuttons are there?

Comment: Use try and catch in the iterate from 0 to big number, you should break the loop when you get the checked box and catch the exception if the check box doesn't exist.

Comment: This will give an error, stating a string does not have the attribute `isChecked`. You can make it work by evaluating `buttonname` first: `buttonname = eval("radio" + str(i)). However, I would not recommend, better to put the radio buttons in a list and iterate over this list.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to work around this problem by using a combination of index and loop.

```
indexOfChecked = [self.ButtonGroup.buttons()[x].isChecked() for x in range(len(self.ButtonGroup.buttons()))].index(True)
```

Comment: Why not simply: `self.ButtonGroup.checkedId()`?

Comment: Somehow that did not work for me when there were multiple button groups. I kept getting entries such as -4,-3 etc :(

Comment: That will only happen if you don't set an ID when adding the buttons. So add them like this: `self.ButtonGroup.addButton(button, index)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def izle(self):
        radios=["radio1","radio2","radio3","radio4"]

        for i in range(0,4):
            selected_radio = self.ui.findChild(QtGui.QRadioButton, self.radios[i])
            if selected_radio.isChecked():
                print selected_radio.objectName() + "is Checked"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all chaild objects of class from desired parent. something like

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        print(self.getCheckedRbName(self.gbRadioButtonsGroup))

    def getCheckedRbName(self, rbParent: QWidget) -> str:
        for rb in rbParent.findChildren(QRadioButton):
            if rb.isChecked():
                return rb.objectName()
```

gives you

```py
#> 'rbThirdOption' is checked
```

Answer (score 0):

As scottydelta's answer doesnt work for PyQt6 here is another solution in the same way but more consistent.

```
for radiobutton in ["button1", "button2", "button3"]:
    if getattr(self, radiobutton).isChecked():
        print(radiobutton, " is checked.")
        # To get the radiobuttons text:
        # print(getattr(self, radiobutton).text())
```

If you dont know the number or names of radiobuttons beforehand you can do this as long as you instantiate the radiobuttons as attributes of your window class.
For example:

```
self.button1 = QRadioButton()
self.button2 = QRadioButton()
attr_objects = [attr_obj for attr_obj in map(lambda x: getattr(self, x), vars(self).keys()) if isinstance(attr_obj, QRadioButton)]
```

With the last lines if condition you restrict the list to radiobutton objects.

Then you can check which of these Objects have certain properties for example if they are checked or not.

```
map(isChecked(), attr_objects)
```