# Trying to check multiple qt radio buttons with python

Tags: python, qt, loops, button, pyqt

I need to check multiple radio buttons from a qt ui with python. 
Up to now we are using something similar to:

```
if main.ui.radioButton_1.isChecked():
    responses["q1"] = "1"
elif main.ui.radioButton_2.isChecked():
    responses["q1"] = "2"
elif main.ui.radioButton_3.isChecked():
    responses["q1"] = "3"

if main.ui.radioButton_4.isChecked():
    responses["q2"] = "1"
elif main.ui.radioButton_5.isChecked():
    responses["q2"] = "2"
elif main.ui.radioButton_6.isChecked():
    responses["q2"] = "3"
...
```

Since there are very many buttons and many different categories (q1, q2, ...) I was thinking of optimizing it a bit. So this is what I hoped would work (adopted from [How to get the checked radiobutton from a groupbox in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402452/how-to-get-the-checked-radiobutton-from-a-groupbox-in-pyqt)):

```
for i, button in enumerate(["main.ui.radioButton_" + str(1) for i in range(1, 8)]):
    if button.isChecked():
        responses["q1"] = str(i - 1)
```

I get why this doesn't work but writing it I hoped it would. 
So I tried to iterate through the buttons using something similar to ([Is there a way to loop through and execute all of the functions in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597827/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-and-execute-all-of-the-functions-in-a-python-clas)):

```
for idx, name, val in enumerate(main.ui.__dict__.iteritems()):
```

and then use some modulo 3 and such to assign the results. But that doesn't work either. Not sure if it's because i used __ dict __ or something else. The error I got was:

```
TypeError: 'QLabel' object is not iterable
```

Now some people could say that implicit is better that explicit and also because of readability the if elif chain is good the way it is but there are 400+ lines of that. Also after reading this post, [Most efficient way of making an if-elif-elif-else statement when the else is done the most?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166074/most-efficient-way-of-making-an-if-elif-elif-else-statement-when-the-else-is-don), I thought there must be a better and more efficient way of doing this (see examples 3.py and 4.py of the of the accepted answer). Because I need to check the Boolean value of main.ui.radioButton_1.isChecked() and then assign thevalue according to the Buttons group (q1, q2,...), I haven't managed to implement the solution using dictionaries as described in the post.

Am I stuck with the if elif chain or is there a way to not only reduce the LOC but also make the code more efficient (faster)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have used Qt Designer to create your ui, so I would suggest putting each set of radio buttons in a [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html). This will give you a simple, ready-made API for getting the checked button in a group without having to query each button individually.

In Qt Designer, buttons can be added to a button-group by selecting them, and then choosing **Assign to button group > New button group** from the context menu. The button IDs (which you will need to use later) are assigned in the order the buttons are selected. So use Ctrl+Click to select each button of a group in the correct order. The IDs start at `1` for each group and just increase by one for each button that is added to that group.

When a new button-group is added, it will appear in the Object Inspector. This will allow you to select it and give it a more meaningful name.

Once you've created all the groups, you can get the checked button of a group like this:

```
    responses["q1"] = str(main.ui.groupQ1.checkedId())
    responses["q2"] = str(main.ui.groupQ2.checkedId())
    # etc...
```

This could be simplified even further to process all the groups in a loop:

```
    for index in range(1, 10):
        key = 'q%d' % index
        group = 'groupQ%d' % index
        responses[key] = str(getattr(main.ui, group).checkedId())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using signals. If you had lots of radio button in an application, I suspect this kind of approach would be noticeably faster. For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MoodExample(QGroupBox):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MoodExample, self).__init__()

        # Create an array of radio buttons
        moods = [QRadioButton("Happy"), QRadioButton("Sad"), QRadioButton("Angry")]

        # Set a radio button to be checked by default
        moods[0].setChecked(True)   

        # Radio buttons usually are in a vertical layout   
        button_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create a button group for radio buttons
        self.mood_button_group = QButtonGroup()

        for i in xrange(len(moods)):
            # Add each radio button to the button layout
            button_layout.addWidget(moods[i])
            # Add each radio button to the button group & give it an ID of i
            self.mood_button_group.addButton(moods[i], i)
            # Connect each radio button to a method to run when it's clicked
            self.connect(moods[i], SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.radio_button_clicked)

        # Set the layout of the group box to the button layout
        self.setLayout(button_layout)

    #Print out the ID & text of the checked radio button
    def radio_button_clicked(self):
        print(self.mood_button_group.checkedId())
        print(self.mood_button_group.checkedButton().text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mood_example = MoodExample()
mood_example.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I found more information at:

http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=387&key=QButtonGroupClick

http://www.pythonschool.net/pyqt/radio-button-widget/